# http request in windows service

Tags: windows-services, httpwebrequest, webrequest

How can we implement like this request:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

in a windows service.

what we are trying to do is this:

run a request from windows service, and when we get the response back,we will save to DB?

**Edit: the service is in C++ native code**

Comment: Is your service in native code, or in .NET?

Comment: the service is in C++ native code

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 0):

In native code you can use the [WinINet library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28VS.85%29.aspx) to make HTTP requests.  The [HttpSendRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method in particular.